# Drop table error in SQL Server 2016 in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, ddl

The below dynamic SQL code is throwing error as:

> The name 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [PHLPS_APAC].[tablea]' is not a valid identifier.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [PHLPS_APAC].[Powersaver]
@PNY INT,
@ID VARCHAR(10),
@SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(30)=[PHLPS_APAC]
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

/*Needs to be DnamicSQL*/
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)

SET @SQL = N'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + QUOTENAME(@SCHEMA_NAME) + N'.[tablea]'; 
EXEC @SQL


SELECT * INTO #temp1 
from tableb as b LEFT JOIN tablec c ON b.OUN=c.[Code]
WHERE a.PNY=@PNY
AND b.ID = @ID


SET @SQL = N'SELECT * into ' + QUOTENAME(@SCHEMA_NAME) + N'.[tablea]  From #temp1';

PRINT @SQL
 
drop tABLE  #temp1
END
```

> The name 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [PHLPS_APAC].[tablea]' is not a valid identifier.

Please help me if I am missing anything.

Comment: If you run the sql 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [PHLPS_APAC].[tablea]' by itself does it work? Maybe missing dbo, as in 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.[PHLPS_APAC].[tablea]'

Comment: @Greg: schema is [PHLPS_APAC]....  When i am doing Drop table IF EXISTS dbo.[PHLPS_APAC].[tablea], it is working.

Comment: Does the old way work, IF OBJECT_ID('[PHLPS_APAC].[tablea]', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE [PHLPS_APAC].[tablea]; ?

Comment: @Greg: Yes Greg.... it's working

Comment: my guess is that whilst you have 2016 installation, the database is not setup for 2016

Comment: @Greg: It is working fine when i am using full dynamic sql ... all code. but when select part is static.... this error is throwing. not sure why... appreciate your suggestion

Comment: In you proc can you see if the table exists before deleting it by running something like 'select * from sysobjects where name like '%tablea%'' & also 'select top 1 * from [PHLPS_APAC].[tablea]'

Comment: @Greg: Thanks Greg, you are right

Comment: EXEC @SQL --> `EXEC (@SQL)`

Comment: `declare @SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(30)=[PHLPS_APAC]` is missinq quotes around the string literal. The error states that `'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [PHLPS_APAC].[tablea]'` is not a valid identifier, not `'[PHLPS_APAC].[tablea]'`. Curious thing, that.

Comment: As already pointed out - to execute a string that contains a dynamic sql statement, you must surround that string with parentheses as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).